# $[0,1]/ \sim$ is $T_4$ space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=[0,1]/ \sim$ be the quotient space where $x\sim y$ if $x=y$ or $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$. My book says that this space is $T_0$ but not $T_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

So far I can show that it is not $T_1$, so consequently not $T_2$, and not $T_3$. How can one go about showing the rest? My problem is that I cannot really picture the open neighbourhood of this space... Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There is one point representing the equivalence class of rationals, an then one point for each irrational. So it is $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$ with the inherited topology, plus a single point $q$ which is in all non-empty open sets.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks. But I am even more confused. How can then this space be $T_0$? For what you say, for every open neighbourhood of $x\in[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, $q$ always belong to it.

Comment: Right, but there is some neighborhood of $q$ which doesn't contain $x$. $T_0$ is very week.

Comment: $T_4$ also implies $T_1$ so is refuted, like $T_3$ and $T_2$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that for any two distinct points $x,y \in [0,1]/\sim,$ there is an open set $U$ such that $x \in U$ and $y \not\in U$ or $y \in U$ and $x \not\in U.$

Let $\pi:[0,1]\to [0,1]/\sim$ be the quotient map and let $q \in [0,1]/\sim$ be the point in which $\mathbf{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is collapsed, so that $\pi^{-1}(\{q\})=\mathbf{Q}\cap[0,1].$

Let $x, y$ be distinct points of $[0,1]/\sim.$ Let $y \neq q,$ so that $y=\{s\}$ with $s$ an irrational number in $[0,1].$ If $x\neq q,$ then $x=\{r\}$ with $r\neq s$ an irrational number in $[0,1].$ Then $U=([0,1]/\sim)-\{y\}$ will work, for $\pi^{-1}(U)=[0,1]-\{s\}$ is open in $[0,1],$ so $U$ is open in $[0,1]/\sim$ and contains $x,$ but $y \not\in U.$ Now, if $x=q,$ similarly, $U=([0,1]/\sim)-\{y\}$ works, for $\pi^{-1}(U)=[0,1]-\{s\}$ is open in $[0,1],$ so $U$ is open in $[0,1]/\sim$ and contains $q,$ but $y\not\in U.$

Comment: Very precise! Thank you! Do you feel like writing the proof for "not being $T_4$"? @positrón0802

Comment: As Henno said in the comments, $T_4$ implies $T_1,$ so it is not $T_4$ as it is not $T_1.$

Comment: Right, forgot about that!

Comment: Most people prefer the definitions where T_4 is equivalent to normal + T_1 but some put them the other way around. From the wording of your question I assume that os the sense you are using. In that case T_4 does not  imply T_1. However,  in this space "not being T_4" (or T_3 or T_2) follows immediately from Thomas Andrews' observation that there are no non-empty disjoint open sets at all.